# Function names in international versions of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, international

I'm writing documentation about how to use Excel functions in a rather company-specific context for novice users.

I noticed that the functions seem to have completely different names in non-English versions of Excel, eg. the `SUM()` function is called `SUMME()` in the German version and something else in the Swedish version.

Is there a way to use the English function names in international versions of Excel?

How do people deal with this madness?

Comment: One possibility is [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/blog/index.php/2013/06/28/tip-easily-insert-an-english-formula-in-your-localized-excel-version-and-have-it-automatically-translated/): "How to use English formula examples in your local Excel version?"

Comment: ASAP Utilities that seems to be a commercial extension that most users probably won't have installed...

Comment: <shrug>. I don't think there is a general solution. You should also read [International Worksheetfunction problems](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win013.htm)

Comment: and [Language, other than US English](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/language.htm)

Comment: No, it isn't possible to use the english formulas in the international version. There's an interesting [vba solution on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247771/excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time)

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution for local Excel versions other than [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/blog/index.php/2013/06/28/tip-easily-insert-an-english-formula-in-your-localized-excel-version-and-have-it-automatically-translated/) which @DavidPostill mentioned. There is Home & Student Edition that is free for home projects, schoolwork and use by charitable organizations.

I am a native Turkish speaker and I came across this problem at various work places in my working life. The only solution I found was to tell the I.T. responsible to install the English version of MS Office on my machine. They didn't want to do it in the first place but after I told them why I needed this, they had to do it.

As a side note, I have found an Excel table using Google which has the *Turkish & English function name conversions* of all Excel functions. I use it when some friends who use Excel in Turkish ask for help.